# Drop Down in not working on my header page in php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i am running a website which buy from some one. website is created on php now i am trying to modifying website header i want to set a drop down menu in my header but drop down is not working on it or may be i am programming in a wrong way.

```
<!-- Nav start -->
    
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="nav-main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a title="" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
          <li class="<?=(current_url()==base_url('cms/cms_page/about-us')) ? 'active':''?>"><a title="" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cms/cms_page/about-us">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a title="" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>training">Training</a></li>
          <li><a title="" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>seeker-login">Post Resume</a></li>
          <li class="<?=(current_url()==base_url('job')) ? 'active':''?>"><a title="" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>job">Government Jobs</a></li>
          <li><a title="" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>contact">Contact Us</a></li>
          
          <li class="yellow"><a href="<?php echo site_url('employer_login') ?>">Employer Site</a></li>
          <li class="black"><a href="<?php echo site_url('seeker-login') ?>">Sign In</a></li>
          <li class="green"><a href="<?php echo site_url('register') ?>">Register</a></li>
          
        </ul>
        
        <!-- Nav collapes end --> 
        
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Nav end -->
```

Here is a code in which i want to set drop down
please any one rewrite code of "Training" with drop down for me with same css.
once i get the idea i will do it my self

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Before you ask please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the css and js code, but maybe the problem is that the bootstrap js script is not included in your website.

Try adding in your header the links to bootstrap:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If it is a Wordpress website, you need to include these links via functions.php file:

```
function your_prefix_scripts() {

   wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapcss', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '5.0.0');
   wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), '5.0.0', true);

}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_prefix_scripts');
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: when i implement these code they effect too much on my header css and  i removed it. please write a training code with drop down

Comment: it's not a wordpress website

Comment: Here is a nice article with a dropdown menu:
https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/